# Creating a SQL view to query whether a node is a descendant of a specific node

Tags: sql, oracle, view, tree, relational-database

I have 2 SQL tables with the following data structure:

Table 1 : FAVORITES

Columns:

- pk
- fk_user (the user table is irrelevant for now)
- fk_tree_node

Table 2 : TREE

Columns:

- pk
- fk_parent_node

I want to create a view from so that I can query, whether a node is favorited/descendant of a favorited node or not. So for every entry in FAVORITES it the view would have several entries where the user is associated with either the favorited node, or a descendant of it.

View: FAV_OR_DESCENDANT

Columns:

- fk_tree_node
- fk_user
- pk

Queries would work like this

```
SELECT *
FROM FAV_OR_DESCENDANT
WHERE fk_user = 0
```

The results I'd expect to get for a given tree would look like this:

Tree:

```
TREE:
+--------+----+----------------+
| rownum | pk | pk_parent_node |
+--------+----+----------------+
|      1 |  1 | null           |
|      2 |  2 | 1              |
|      3 |  3 | 2              |
|      4 |  4 | 1              |
+--------+----+----------------+

FAVORITES:
+--------+----+---------+--------------+
| rownum | pk | fk_user | fk_tree_node |
+--------+----+---------+--------------+
|      1 |  0 |       0 |            1 |
+--------+----+---------+--------------+

Tree representation:

       1 <-- User 0 has only favorited this single node
      / \
     2   4
    /
   3
```

Result data in FAV_OR_DESCENDANT:

```
+--------+---------+--------------+
| rownum | fk_user | fk_tree_node |
+--------+---------+--------------+
|      1 |       0 |            1 |
|      2 |       0 |            2 |
|      3 |       0 |            3 |
|      4 |       0 |            4 |
+--------+---------+--------------+
```

I know how to write this query if I'm asking for all favorited nodes/descendant nodes for a specific user. However, I'm struggling in translating that into an SQL query that would create a view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tree
START WITH tree.pk IN (
    SELECT fk_tree_node
    FROM favorites
    WHERE fk_user = 0
)
CONNECT BY PRIOR tree.pk = tree.fk_parent_node
```

Other questions I found where more centered around making queries or were not limited by SQL. I'd be thankful for every hint in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide actual table definitions (ddl - stripped to only relevant columns if desired) and sample data, as [formatted test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/easier-way-to-represent-db-tables-when-asking-db-questions) - **no images**.  Or even a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: What is `category_lid`. Why in your SQL attempt you have `select * from tree` when from the desired output it is clear you want the first column to come from the other table?

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you need to get all descendant nodes, you need to aggregate all parent nodes, for example using `sys_connect_by_path` (or you can use hierarchical recursive subquery factoring):

```sql
with 
TREE(pk, pk_parent_node) as (
    select 1 , null from dual union all
    select 2 , 1    from dual union all
    select 3 , 2    from dual union all
    select 4 , 1    from dual
)
,FAVORITES( pk, fk_user, fk_tree_node) as (
    select 0, 0, 1 from dual
)
,v_tree as (
    select pk,pk_parent_node,sys_connect_by_path(pk,'/') p_path
    from TREE
    start with pk_parent_node is null
    connect by prior pk = pk_parent_node
)
select *
from v_tree;
```

Results:

```
        PK PK_PARENT_NODE P_PATH
---------- -------------- ------------------------------
         1 NULL           /1
         2              1 /1/2
         3              2 /1/2/3
         4              1 /1/4
```

In fact you can already check if `P_PATH` contains a favorite node, but since you want a view with users, we can aggregate them into a new column:

```sql
with 
TREE(pk, pk_parent_node) as (
    select 1 , null from dual union all
    select 2 , 1    from dual union all
    select 3 , 2    from dual union all
    select 4 , 1    from dual
)
,FAVORITES( pk, fk_user, fk_tree_node) as (
    select 0, 0, 1 from dual union all
    select 1, 1, 3 from dual
)
,v_tree as (
    select pk,pk_parent_node,sys_connect_by_path(pk,'/')||'/' p_path
    from TREE
    start with pk_parent_node is null
    connect by prior pk = pk_parent_node
)
select 
   v.*, v2.*
from v_tree v
     outer apply(
        select 
           xmlelement(USERS, xmlagg(xmlelement(ID, f.pk) order by f.pk)) as users
        from FAVORITES f
        where p_path like '%/'||f.fk_tree_node||'/%'
     ) v2;
```

Results:

```
       PK PK_PARENT_NODE P_PATH                         USERS
---------- -------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 NULL           /1/                            <USERS><ID>0</ID></USERS>
         2              1 /1/2/                          <USERS><ID>0</ID></USERS>
         3              2 /1/2/3/                        <USERS><ID>0</ID><ID>1</ID></USERS>
         4              1 /1/4/                          <USERS><ID>0</ID></USERS>
```

I've added one more user 1 to make it more clear.

So now you just need to add a predicate to filter users:

```sql
with 
TREE(pk, pk_parent_node) as (
    select 1 , null from dual union all
    select 2 , 1    from dual union all
    select 3 , 2    from dual union all
    select 4 , 1    from dual
)
,FAVORITES( pk, fk_user, fk_tree_node) as (
    select 0, 0, 1 from dual union all
    select 1, 1, 3 from dual
)
,v_tree as (
    select pk,pk_parent_node,sys_connect_by_path(pk,'/')||'/' p_path
    from TREE
    start with pk_parent_node is null
    connect by prior pk = pk_parent_node
)
,v_final_view as (
    select 
       v.*, v2.*
    from v_tree v
         outer apply(
            select 
               xmlelement(USERS, xmlagg(xmlelement(ID, f.pk) order by f.pk)) as users
            from FAVORITES f
            where p_path like '%/'||f.fk_tree_node||'/%'
         ) v2
)
select *
from v_final_view
where 
   xmlexists(
      '$USERS/USERS[ID=$USER_ID]' 
      passing 
        users as USERS, 
        1 as USER_ID -- your input param - user id
    )
;
```

Results:

```sql
  PK PK_PARENT_NODE P_PATH       USERS
---- -------------- ------------ ------------------------------------
   3              2 /1/2/3/      <USERS><ID>0</ID><ID>1</ID></USERS>
```

Of course, it's just an example of this approach, so you can use other functions for aggregation or even create materialized view for performance.